# Tkinter - User Input is not being returned after entering in input box

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Good afternoon,

Noob coder here.

I have scoured these forums and found somewhat similar questions but I have struggled with extrapolating it to my particular example.

I am able to get my input box to populate although after hitting the "Plot" button, I am unable to get the input values from each entry box to print. If I enter anything, all I ever get is the following output:

`.!frame.!entry
.!frame2.!entry
.!frame3.!entry
.!frame4.!entry
.!frame5.!entry
.!frame6.!entry`

Here is my code thus far:

```
import tkinter as tk

fields = ('Input panel major length',
 'Input panel intermediate length', 'Input drillhole average length',
  'Input Conversion rate', 'Geostats Interpolation Parameters: Major (Z)',
  'Geostats Interpolation Parameters: Intermediate (Y)')

def calcs(values):
    for value in values:
        print(values[value])

def makelines(root, fields):
    entries = {}
    for field in fields:
        row = tk.Frame(root)
        lab = tk.Label(row, width=50, text=field+": ", anchor='w')
        ent = tk.Entry(row)
        row.pack(side=tk.TOP, 
                 fill=tk.X, 
                 padx=5, 
                 pady=5)
        lab.pack(side=tk.LEFT)
        ent.pack(side=tk.RIGHT, 
                 expand=tk.YES, 
                 fill=tk.X)
        entries[field] = ent
    return entries

if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.title('Plot')
    root.geometry('800x400')
    ents = makelines(root, fields)
    b2 = tk.Button(root, text='Quit', command=root.quit)
    b2.pack(side=tk.RIGHT, padx=5, pady=5)
    b1 = tk.Button(root, text='Plot',
        command=(lambda e=ents: calcs(e)))
    b1.pack(side=tk.LEFT, padx=5, pady=5)
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: First you have to understand [Event-driven_programming](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event-driven_programming). Read through [`[tkinter] event driven programming`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=is%3Aanswer+%5Btkinter%5D+event+driven+programming+entry)

Comment: entry widgets have a `get` method specifically for getting the value out of the widget.

Answer (score 1):

You are calling `calcs` with a dictionary containing `Entry` widgets indexed by a string.
So when you do

```
for value in values:
    print(values[value])
```

you are printing the widgets themselves, not their contents.

Instead, try using the `get()` method of the `Entry` widgets:

```
for value in values:
    print(values[value].get())
```

You could also use the `values()` method of a dictionary to iterate over the values instead of over the keys:

```
def calcs(wdict):
    for w in wdict.values():
        print(w.get())
```

Comment: Ugh this was a perfect answer. Thank you very much for your time.